# Add IE specific CSS in angular ( version 1.2 ) application

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer, gruntjs

In my angular application i want to add conditional IE css for IE8, IE9 and i have added them this way in my index file

```
<!-- Application main stylesheet -->

<link href="styles/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/app.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->

<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/basic.ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/basic.ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But while running on **dist** grunt merges all css into one minified file and this css files are not there while my index file detects browser mode IE .

Do i have to make changes in **grunt task** that it will allows this file sto go without minification or there is any other way to put them in angular application.

Please provide solution.

Gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2014-07-14 using generator-angular 0.9.5
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
     app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
     dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

     // Project settings
     yeoman: appConfig,

     // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
     watch: {
        bower: {
          files: ['bower.json'],
          tasks: ['wiredep']
        },
        js: {
          files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/{,*/}*.js'],
          tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
          options: {
             livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
          }
        },
        jsTest: {
          files: ['test/spec/**/{,*/}*.js'],
          tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
        },
        styles: {
          files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/**/{,*/}*.css'],
          tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        gruntfile: {
          files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        livereload: {
          options: {
             livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
          },
          files: [
             '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/{,*/}*.html',
             '.tmp/styles/**/{,*/}*.css',
             '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
          ]
        }
     },

     // The actual grunt server settings
     connect: {
        options: {
          port: 4000,
          // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
          hostname: '0.0.0.0',
          livereload: 35728
        },
        livereload: {
          options: {
             open: true,
             middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                  connect.static('.tmp'),
                  connect().use(
                     '/bower_components',
                     connect.static('./bower_components')
                  ),
                  connect.static(appConfig.app)
                ];
             }
          }
        },
        test: {
          options: {
             port: 4001,
             middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                  connect.static('.tmp'),
                  connect.static('test'),
                  connect().use(
                     '/bower_components',
                     connect.static('./bower_components')
                  ),
                  connect.static(appConfig.app)
                ];
             }
          }
        },
        dist: {
          options: {
             open: true,
             base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          }
        }
     },

     // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
     jshint: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'jshintrc',
          reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: {
          src: [
             'Gruntfile.js',
             '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/{,*/}*.js'
          ]
        },
        test: {
          options: {
             jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
          },
          src: ['test/spec/**/{,*/}*.js']
        }
     },

     // Empties folders to start fresh
     clean: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
             dot: true,
             src: [
                '.tmp',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
             ]
          }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
     },

     // Add vendor prefixed styles
     autoprefixer: {
        options: {
          browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
          files: [{
             expand: true,
             cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
             src: '{,*/}*.css',
             dest: '.tmp/styles/'
          }]
        }
     },

     // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
     wiredep: {
        app: {
          src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
          ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
        }
     },

     // Renames files for browser caching purposes
     filerev: {
        dist: {
          src: [
             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
     },

     // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
     // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
     // additional tasks can operate on them
     useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          flow: {
             html: {
                steps: {
                  js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                  css: ['cssmin']
                },
                post: {}
             }
          }
        }
     },

     // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
     usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
          assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
        }
     },

     // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
     // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
     // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
     // to use the Usemin blocks.
     // cssmin: {
     //   dist: {
     //     files: {
     //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
     //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
     //       ]
     //     }
     //   }
     // },
     // uglify: {
     //   dist: {
     //     files: {
     //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
     //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
     //       ]
     //     }
     //   }
     // },
     // concat: {
     //   dist: {}
     // },

     imagemin: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
             expand: true,
             cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
             src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
             dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
          }]
        }
     },

     svgmin: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
             expand: true,
             cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
             src: '{,*/}*.svg',
             dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
          }]
        }
     },

     htmlmin: {
        dist: {
          options: {
             collapseWhitespace: true,
             conservativeCollapse: true,
             collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
             removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
             removeOptionalTags: true
          },
          files: [{
             expand: true,
             cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
             src: ['*.html', 'views/**/{,*/}*.html'],
             dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          }]
        }
     },

     // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
     // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
     // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
     ngmin: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
             expand: true,
             cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
             src: '*.js',
             dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
          }]
        }
     },

     // Replace Google CDN references
     cdnify: {
        dist: {
          html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
        }
     },

     // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
     copy: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
             expand: true,
             dot: true,
             cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
             dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
             src: [
                '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                '.htaccess',
                '*.html',
                '*.json',
                'views/**/{,*/}*.html',
                'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                'fonts/*'
             ]
          }, {
             expand: true,
             cwd: '.tmp/images',
             dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
             src: ['generated/*']
          }, {
             expand: true,
             cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
             src: 'fonts/*',
             dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          }, {
             expand: true,
             cwd: 'bower_components/fontawesome',
             src: 'fonts/*',
             dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          }]
        },
        styles: {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
     },

     // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
     concurrent: {
        server: [
          'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
          'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
          'copy:styles',
          'imagemin',
          'svgmin'
        ]
     },

     // Test settings
     karma: {
        unit: {
          configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
          singleRun: true
        }
     }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
     if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
     } else if (target === 'prod') {
        return grunt.task.run(['prod', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
     } else if (target === 'staging') {
        return grunt.task.run(['staging', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
     }

     grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'ngconstant:dev',
        'wiredep',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
     ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
     grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
     grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
     'clean:server',
     'concurrent:test',
     'autoprefixer',
     'connect:test',
     'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
     'clean:dist',
     'wiredep',
     'ngconstant:dist',
     'useminPrepare',
     'concurrent:dist',
     'autoprefixer',
     'concat',
     'ngmin',
     'copy:dist',
     'cdnify',
     'cssmin',
     'uglify',
     'filerev',
     'usemin',
     'htmlmin'
  ]);

     /**
  * Production configuration : use grunt serve:prod
  */
  grunt.registerTask('prod', [
     'clean:dist',
     'wiredep',
     'ngconstant:prod',
     'useminPrepare',
     'concurrent:dist',
     'autoprefixer',
     'concat',
     'ngmin',
     'copy:dist',
     'cdnify',
     'cssmin',
     'uglify',
     'filerev',
     'usemin',
     'htmlmin'
  ]);

  /**
  * Staging configuration : use grunt serve:staging
  */
  grunt.registerTask('staging', [
     'clean:dist',
     'wiredep',
     'ngconstant:staging',
     'useminPrepare',
     'concurrent:dist',
     'autoprefixer',
     'concat',
     'ngmin',
     'copy:dist',
     'cdnify',
     'cssmin',
     'uglify',
     'filerev',
     'usemin',
     'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
     'newer:jshint',
     'test',
     'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: Please post your grunt code in the question.

Comment: @OriDrori can you tell me which part of grunt is responsible for it so i put that part here as there mutiple task runs

Comment: Look for the part that extract the links to the css, and concatenate it. You can always post all the grunt code to a fiddle or something like that.

Comment: Just a note, what version of angular are you using? Because angular 1.3. doesn't support IE8.

Comment: @OriDrori i have added my gruntfile for your reference.

Comment: @Vucko I am using angular 1.2 . my question is not that is it not working, it is how can i add browser specific CSS what we do in any normal application using simple code in index file

Comment: There is a problem with usemin and conditional comments. I'm trying to find a way around it.

Comment: @OriDori any solutions on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my answer and that is so simple.

Just write your css as :

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/basic.ie.css -->
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/basic.ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Its done :)